# How to filter CSV data using C#

Tags: c#, string, csv

I have a csv file containing string data, I would like to filter out all data rows if the "Job" column is empty,  create a new csv file and write the remaining data rows into it.

The string data contains double quote "", The "Id", "Name", "Job" in the first line are actually string data, not column, which means that if the third string data of a data row is double quote "" , it's filtered out.

```
"Id" , "Name"    , "Job"
"1"  , "Alan"    , "Engineer"
"2"  , "Bob"     , "Technician"
"3"  , "Charlie" , ""
"4"  , "Danny"   , ""
```

The remaining data according to the csv above are expected to be

```
"Id" , "Name"    , "Job"
"1"  , "Alan"    , "Engineer"
"2"  , "Bob"     , "Technician"
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What i do ? I convert the csv to excel then use excel upload form and get the values in c# and process them and then put them in another excel or csv file. For Excel upload reference check this link => https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Import-data-from-Excel-file-to-SQL-Server-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx

Comment: Are you formatting these examples to show us the "columns" pretty aligned or do you really have all those spaces between "columns"?

Comment: @Thameem, Excell to read a CSV? That's a really heavy tool for nothing. Something like CSVHelper is more suited.

Comment: @Steve, speaking of the right tool that's a `csvReader.Configuration.TrimOptions` no big deals.

Comment: @xdtTransform. Oh i didnt know that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have csv helper tools,you can use tools parse file to List or DataTable,filter data and export.

If you don't have,you can try:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(sourcePath))
            {
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(destiPath))
                {
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        var list = line.Split(',');
                        if (list.Length > 2 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(list[2].Trim(' ','\"')))
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(line);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you, this one is easier to understand, it gives me some inspiration on string manipulation

Comment: Its not a csv helper tool that is standard parsing

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using something like this:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("csvFile.csv");
List<string[]> csvData = new List<string[]>();
foreach(string line in lines)
{
    using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(new StringReader(line)))
    {
        parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
        parser.SetDelimiters(",");
        parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
        parser.TrimWhiteSpace = true;
        while (!parser.EndOfData)
            csvData.Add(parser.ReadFields());
    }
}

//Select all lines in csv file in which third column are not empty
List<string[]> filteredCsvData = csvData.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x[2])).ToList();

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string[] line in filteredCsvData)
{
    //Quote all columns back
    string[] quotedLine = Array.ConvertAll(line, x => '"' + x + '"');
    builder.AppendLine(string.Join(',', quotedLine));
}
File.WriteAllText ("newCsvFile.csv", builder.ToString());
```

If you need to quote only those columns that have commas use: `string[] quotedLine = Array.ConvertAll(line, x => '"' + x + '"');`

**NOTE** following code uses Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser as CSV parser to use it in .Net Framework you need to include Microsoft.VisualBasic to your project (also available in .Net Core 3.0)

Comment: Thank you, your answer is easy to understand and has given me some inspiration, but I've me some problem with adding VB.FileIO reference, the problem is solved now

Answer (score 1):

#### Step1: Read the CSV and  make  a List object.

With the Poco class :

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public string Job { get; set; }
}
```

You can use [CSV helper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) to read  with the following configuration:

```
Configuration.Delimiter=",";
Configuration.HasHeaderRecord=false; // has your first line look like header but is not
Configuration.TrimOptions= TrimOptions.Trim | TrimOptions.InsideQuotes;
Configuration.RegisterClassMap<FooMap>();
```

#### Step2: Filter the result

```
records.Where(x=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Job))
```

Complete code exemple, and [live demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qxQ85N):

```
        var input = @"""Id"" , ""Name""    , ""Job""
""1""  , ""Alan""    , ""Engineer""
""2""  , ""Bob""     , ""Technician""
""3""  , ""Charlie"" , """"
""4""  , ""Danny""   , """"";

        var records= new List<Foo>();

        //reading CSV to List Foo;
        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(input))
        using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader))
        {
            csvReader.Configuration.Delimiter=",";
            csvReader.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord=false; 
            csvReader.Configuration.TrimOptions=TrimOptions.Trim | TrimOptions.InsideQuotes;
            csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<FooMap>();
            records = csvReader.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList();
        }

        records.Dump();

        //Filter
        var result = records.Where(x=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Job)).ToList();
        result.Dump();
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }        
        public string Job { get; set; }
    }
    public class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo>
    {
        public FooMap()
        {
            Map(m => m.Id).Index(0);
            Map(m => m.Name).Index(1);          
            Map(m => m.Job).Index(2);

            //mapping with column header
            /*Map(m => m.Id).Name("Id");
            Map(m => m.Name).Name("Name");          
            Map(m => m.Job).Name("Job");*/
        }
    }
```